# How did castles with large moats obtain protected drinking water?

Tags: castles

Clarification: I expect that many different options were realised, so as long as you have one historical example of your solution, it is a valid answer for me.

Background: I recall that a major effort in building castles had to do with digging the well. Particularly for hill castles. This was motivated by the [practice of poisoning external wells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castle_well) and contributed to the emergence of [castle cisterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cistern#Castle_cisterns).

But many castles I have seen posses huge moats. For example [Chateau du Plessis-Bourré](http://www.plessis-bourre.com/en/):
[image]
Such moats must have been very easy to pollute with carcasses and apparently the castle inhabitants often dumped their faeces there (see comment by Steve Bird).

In the presence of this dirty moat water, was the well still dug as normal, or were cisterns preferred? How far beneath the moat level would one need to go? Did they even have [casing](https://wellowner.org/resources/basics/well-system-components/) techniques capable of preventing the influx of dirty surface water ( I have no idea how well bricks can do that).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castle_well) lists some castles with exceptionally deep wells, but none of these seem to be moated.

Comment: Also moats were often where the latrines emptied into.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Why wouldn't they dig a well the same as any other castle?  Obviously the water table is near the surface.  There seems to be an assumption that they would abandon the safety of a well in favor of the risk of a moat. Why would you assume that?  or are you assuming that fouling the moat would foul the acquifier, and therefore the well?  I just don't understand what the presence of a moat has to do with the existence of a well or cistern.

Comment: @MCW probably I just don’t know enough about wells and ground water. Is it enough to dig the well as usual or do you have to go way, way deeper in the direct vicinity of that dirty moat?

Comment: Also note that "Unlike many other famous castles, no historical records exist regarding conflicts of war associated with Château du Plessis-Bourré." - this specific castle never needed to worry about the problem

Comment: The answer is probably found in [Wikipedia:Well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well#:~:text=2.1,Dug%20wells).  If I were researching further, I'd try to find out the state of well when relevant castles were built, and the probability of contamination of the aquifer at the distance to the castle walls.     But those aren't in your question.  (Please edit your question rather than replying in comments.  People who want to do research to answer your question are more likely to do so if the question is completely and clearly articulated.)

Comment: this seems rather broad

Comment: If you can build a cistern that prevents water from seeping out, you can also build a well casing that can prevent water from seeping in. Materials known to be used for that purpose at least since antiquity include clay, cob, mortar or plaster. ["Impervious (brick) wells are made using masonry with cement or lime mortar."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brick-lined_well#Design)

Comment: @ccprog if the depth makes no difference, in the construction, then obviously both tasks are similar. Thank you, I will check it out.

Comment: Plessis-Bourre (built in 1468) just squeaks by, but a number of the Loire Valley castles with similar big moats seem to have been constructed past the times during which castles were expected to withstand sieges, because artillery came in and rendered them obsolete in the [1490s](https://weaponsandwarfare.com/2019/06/14/fortress-warfare-in-renaissance-italy/).